# How do I create an XMLStreamReader that can continue in case of a "fatal" error?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to seek into a huge XML file, start reading XML data from a byte position, basically reading a chunk. I'm creating an `XMLStreamReader` like this:

```
final XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
```

This reader can start reading at *any* position in the stream, but I want it to skip stuff until it finds the start of a tag. I do not want it to validate anything.

For example, it could start reading this, in the middle of `firstAttr`:

```
rstAttr='12345' secondAttr='QWERTY'>
</endElement>
<startReadingAtLeastFromHere>
...
```

I don't really need to read the `</endElement>`, but I want the parser to read at least `<startReadingAtLeastFromHere>` and all content after that.

My problem is that `factory.setXMLReporter(reporter)` is not invoked, so I cannot use that to tell the reader to continue.

I'm not specifying the `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory` system property for now, and it defaults to Sun's `XMLInputFactoryImpl`. It uses `StaxErrorReporter`, which has a field named `fContinueAfterFatalError`, but I can't find how to change its value, or how to replace the `StaxErrorReporter` with my own.

If that's too tricky, is there any pull-based XML parser that can be configured to ignore errors and keep reading?

Comment: Personally I've used Akka Supervisors to catch fatal errors and restart the thread so the process keeps going on. Check this out: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html

Comment: Hello Nicolas Marchildon, i guess you question is already out of date, but i'm wondering: if you're not interested int the tags, then why do you read the document with an xml-reader? wouldn't a simply text-read be sufficient, you just have to read some tags, in which you are interested?